# Passing function to another page in PHP

Tags: php

So this has been bugging me for sometime, I want to pass a calculation which I have stored in a function onto another page, I can pass field entries no problem (sorry im newish at PHP) but how do i pass my calculation from:

// calculation section (calculator.php) - this is a include on every page
The calculation is made by a users entries which is in a include on every page

// The thank-you.php page outputs a thank you comment and sends the email
I receive all the other info fine but the function won't come through in my email.
The output from the calculation is also stored in calculator.php which is the include but it outputs to the screen fine just not to my email :(.

Am I missing something?

Sorry (edit) here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['to'])){

ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');
$now = date("H:i");

$cutoff = "06:00";
$higherthan = "22:00";


    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'];
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$returndate = $_REQUEST['returndate'];
$people = $_REQUEST['people'];
$return = $_REQUEST['return'];
$myemail = $_REQUEST['myemail'];

include_once('includes/config.php');

$settingsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfers_in WHERE location='$to' AND no_passengers='$people'");
$settings        = mysql_fetch_assoc($settingsSql);

echo "From: ".$from." To: ".$settings['location']."<br />";
echo "Number of passengers: ".$settings['no_passengers']."<br />";

ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');
$now = date("H:i");

$cutoff = "06:00";
$higherthan = "22:00";

echo "Time cost: ".$settings['price']." euros<br /><hr />Total: ";



    function timeCost() {

        $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
        $people = $_REQUEST['people'];
        $return = $_REQUEST['return'];

        include_once('includes/config.php');

        $settingsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfers_in WHERE location='$to' AND no_passengers='$people'");
        $settings        = mysql_fetch_assoc($settingsSql);

        //echo $return;

        if ($return == "No"){
            if ((strtotime($now) < strtotime($cutoff)) || (strtotime($now) > strtotime($higherthan))){
                echo number_format($settings['price']) + 1.40;
            } else {
                echo number_format($settings['price']) + 0.00;
            }
        } elseif ($return == "Yes") {
            if ((strtotime($now) < strtotime($cutoff)) || (strtotime($now) > strtotime($higherthan))){
                echo number_format($settings['price']) * 2 + 1.40;
            } else {
                echo number_format($settings['price']) * 2 + 0.00;
            }
        }

        echo " in euros<br /><br />";   
    }

    echo timeCost();


} else { ?>

<form method="POST" action="thank-you.php" name="chooseDateForm" id="chooseDateForm">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="name" />

            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="telephone" />

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="myemail" />

            <label>From:</label>
            <select name="from">
                <option selected="selected">Malaga</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <label>To:</label>
            <select name="to">

<?php foreach ($data as $place => $price){
    echo "<option>{$place}</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="date" name="date" class="date-pick" />
            <span id="calendar"></span>

            <div id="return-journey">
                <label>Return Date:</label>
                <input type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="returndate" name="returndate" class="date-pick" />
                <span id="calendar"></span>
            </div>

            <label>Number of people:</label>
            <select id="people" name="people">
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <div id="return">
                <label>Is this a return<br />journey?</label>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <div id="radio-buttons">
                    <input type="radio" name="return" value="Yes" class="radio returning" />Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="return" value="No" class="radio" checked />No
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="fauxButton" />            

        </form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: you should add the relevant code for us in order to help you

Comment: have you tried post variables?

Comment: You probably want [serialize](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the function and store it in the [session](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)? Also, you should give this design very serious, high-level thought. It sounds like a prime target for XSS vulnerabilities to pass anything made by the user to another page, where it's going to be invoked as a function. We'd really need some relevant code to give a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using sessions, you can store the variable, results, array -- whatever into a session variable and then retrieve it on a new page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test_var'] = 'Jake';
```

Then when I navigate to a new page and retrieve the var:

```
    session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test_var'] 
    // outputs 'Jake'
```

Comment: Hi Jake, That's great thanks, I seem to be having a problem though with it sending the info through but if i do it as a few words:

    `session_start();
    $_SESSION['timeCost'] = 'hello world';  //timeCost()`

It sends hello world no problem to my email but it won't send the timeCost() function. Am I missing something out?

Comment: So I discovered that I needed to change the echo in the calculation and then just store the function as a session and it works beautifully :) Thank you everyone much appreciated!